# Añadir directorio nuevo en GIT

Tags: git

Tengo un proyecto en el que estoy usando GIT como sistema de control de versiones. Es un directorio donde generé el init, y al que luego he ido añadiendo otros directorios, digamos que es una especie de curso en el que cada directorio añadido es un nuevo tema.

En una de las ocasiones me equivoqué, y dentro de un directorio nuevo que creé, también creé otro nuevo init dentro de él. Después, fuera de ese directorio (en el padre digamos) intenté actualizar añadiendo todos los cambios, pero ya no me dejaba porque había otro init interno. Procedí a borrar este init interno y su directorio .git pero ya no me actualiza los cambios aunque los añada. Todo lo que modifico dentro de ese directorio es como si no lo viese. ¿Tiene arreglo?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando dices que "creaste un init" te refieres a que hiciste `git init` dentro de él? En ese caso lo que habrá ocurrido será que ha creado una carpeta `.git` en el sitio en que estabas cuando hiciste `git init`, y por tanto mientras estés en esa carpeta _o en cualquiera de sus descendientes_, el repositorio que usará será ese en lugar del "padre". Borrar la carpeta `.git` debería arreglar el problema. Parece que en tu caso no es así, pero no puedo saber qué está pasando exactamente. ¿Qué ocurre cuando haces `git add fichero` en esa carpeta? ¿Qué muestra `git status`? ¿O `git remote -v`?

Comment: ¿No tendrás más carpetas `.git` dentro de la principal? Ponte en lo que consideras la "raíz" de tu repositorio "principal" y haz `find . -name .git -print` ¿Te muestra más de una? Si no es así, tal vez añadiste la carpeta conflictiva al `.gitignore`.

Comment: En la carpeta padre cuando hago git add . o git add <carpeta> no me dice nada. Cuando hago un git status me dice que no hay nada para hacer commit.

Comment: No tengo nada en .gitignore más que un archivo .zip

Comment: Igual es que la carpeta en cuestión está vacía. Git no puede añadir carpetas vacías a un repositorio. Asegúrate de que tenga algo, aunque sea un fichero vacío.

Comment: Es una cosa rarísima que no me había pasado. No está vacía la carpeta, tengo un montón de archivos dentro. He intentado con git add -i y luego usando el update y demás pero no hay manera.

Comment: Igual ya están todos bajo control de versiones.... Entra en esa carpeta y haz un `git log .` para ver la historia de esa carpeta. Si te aparece al menos un commit es que ya estaba versionada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89581/discussion-between-abulafia-and-kalasni).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que a mi se me ocurre y creo que es lo mas sencillo es clonar tu repositorio anterior, la ultima version que tenias funcionando, remplazar los archivos que sufrieron cambios, agregar estos a git ( `git all .` ), y subirlos.

Comment: Algo parecido estoy pensando hacer, sí.